# Dynamically added text box is appended to the wrong form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-forms

It will be easy to see using this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xPye/4/

What I have is two dropdowns whose values change depending on what you select in the first.

This all works fine, even with the form submission but what I want to do now is for some values in the first drop down, is to produce the middle dropdown and a text box instead of 2 dropdowns.

I have it slightly working but if you choose `escherpropname` first, it breaks the dynamic elements that are added afterwards.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to change the way you're adding a textbox, here's one solution

HTML:

```
<!-- remove textbox -->
<!--<input type="text" name="valuestextbox[]" class="valuestextbox"/>-->
```

jQuery:

```
// in document .ready change these lines
//$valuestextbox = $('.valuestextbox'); *remove*
//$valuestextbox.hide(); *remove*
// Create a textbox as needed
$valuestextbox = $('<input type="text" name="valuestextbox[]" class="valuestextbox"/>'); // *add*

...

// in your test for 'escherpropname'
//$valuestextbox.show(); *remove*
$values.after($valuestextbox.clone()); // *add*
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/6xPye/5/

Comment: thank you, that seems to work amazingly well. I am just finished work so will give it a try tomorrow and accept your answer.

I have one more question on how to implement the text box in my sql query if it has a textbox instead of a dropdown but I can ask you that tomorrow if that is ok?

Thanks,

Martn

Comment: just made the changes, a quick question I have is if you select `escherpropname` butthen change it to `agent` for example, the text box still remains so I was wondering the best way to re-hide the text box and show the dropdown instead? Normally I would use `.show()` and `.hide()` but this line is throwing me off `$values.after($valuestextbox.clone());`

Comment: in your check to go back to `agent` you can remove the select the textbox with `$(this).parent().find(".valuestextbox").remove();` and re-show the values drop down `$values.show();`.